# Spring Data Neo4j 5's EntityScan includes companion objects when using Kotlin

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, kotlin, spring-data-neo4j-5

I am using Spring Data 5 via Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4.

I noticed that when using `@EntityScan` and providing a package, it includes scanning of 'inner' classes that are generated by Kotlin. In my example below, I only have one property, but I have also tried `companion object { <property here> }` and it still errors out.

**Is there anyway to filter out these internal classes that Kotlin generates?**

Here is the exception I am getting:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class is an internal synthetic class generated by the Kotlin compiler, such as an anonymous class for a lambda, a SAM wrapper, a callable reference, etc. It's not a Kotlin class or interface, so the reflection library has no idea what declarations does it have. Please use Java reflection to inspect this class: class com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model.Store$properties$3`

***Full Stacktrace:***

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storeController' defined in file [C:\Users\jimpo\IdeaProjects\myboothinventory\mbi-test\target\classes\com\mybusinessincorp\mbitest\web\StoreController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storeRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class is an internal synthetic class generated by the Kotlin compiler, such as an anonymous class for a lambda, a SAM wrapper, a callable reference, etc. It's not a Kotlin class or interface, so the reflection library has no idea what declarations does it have. Please use Java reflection to inspect this class: class com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model.Store$properties$3
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:745) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:214) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1126) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M4.jar:2.0.0.M4]
    at com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.MbiTestApplicationKt.main(MbiTestApplication.kt:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storeRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class is an internal synthetic class generated by the Kotlin compiler, such as an anonymous class for a lambda, a SAM wrapper, a callable reference, etc. It's not a Kotlin class or interface, so the reflection library has no idea what declarations does it have. Please use Java reflection to inspect this class: class com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model.Store$properties$3
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1607) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:275) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:832) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:737) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class is an internal synthetic class generated by the Kotlin compiler, such as an anonymous class for a lambda, a SAM wrapper, a callable reference, etc. It's not a Kotlin class or interface, so the reflection library has no idea what declarations does it have. Please use Java reflection to inspect this class: class com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model.Store$properties$3
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class is an internal synthetic class generated by the Kotlin compiler, such as an anonymous class for a lambda, a SAM wrapper, a callable reference, etc. It's not a Kotlin class or interface, so the reflection library has no idea what declarations does it have. Please use Java reflection to inspect this class: class com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model.Store$properties$3
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.reportUnresolvedClass(KClassImpl.kt:289) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.access$reportUnresolvedClass(KClassImpl.kt:42) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:52) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:43) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt:172) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructorDescriptors(KClassImpl.kt:186) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:90) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:43) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getConstructors(KClassImpl.kt) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructors(KClassImpl.kt:222) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.getPrimaryConstructor(KClasses.kt:40) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.1.51.jar:1.1.51]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.lambda$discover$2(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:165) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jPersistentEntity.<init>(Neo4jPersistentEntity.java:56) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:64) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:44) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:376) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:343) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.lambda$new$1(Neo4jMappingContext.java:57) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1620) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.<init>(Neo4jMappingContext.java:57) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.Neo4jMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(Neo4jMappingContextFactoryBean.java:62) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.Neo4jMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(Neo4jMappingContextFactoryBean.java:31) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.0.RC3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:141) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC4.jar:5.0.0.RC4]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

I have created a sample project below to help out.

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mybusinessincorp</groupId>
    <artifactId>mbi-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mbi-test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.1.51</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>au.com.console</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>kassava</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.0.0</version>-->
            <!--<exclusions>-->
                <!--<exclusion>-->
                    <!--<groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>-->
                <!--</exclusion>-->
            <!--</exclusions>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

***MbiTestApplication.kt***

```
package com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model")
class MbiTestApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(MbiTestApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

***/model/Store.kt***

```
package com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Index
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Transient

@NodeEntity
data class Store(

    var id: Long? = null,

    @Index(unique = true)
    var storeId: Long? = null,

    var name: String? = null

) {
    @Transient
    private val properties = arrayOf(Store::id, Store::storeId, Store::name)
}
```

***/domain/StoreRepository.kt***

```
package com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.domain

import com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model.Store
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional


/**
 * Repository for [Store]s
 * */
@Repository
@Transactional
interface StoreRepository : Neo4jRepository<Store, Long>
```

***/web/StoreController.kt***

```
package com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.web

import com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.domain.StoreRepository
import com.mybusinessincorp.mbitest.model.Store
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("stores")
class StoreController
constructor(private val storeRepository: StoreRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/", "/allStores")
    fun allStores(): Iterable<Store> = storeRepository.findAll(1)
}
```

***application.yml***

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myboothinventory-test
  data:
    neo4j:
      uri: bolt://localhost:7687
      username: neo4j
      password: <password>
security:
    basic:
        enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed in the Kay release.
See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1171.
This seems also related to a kotlin bug described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20442).

Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5 fixes the problem.

Comment: Looks like it is due to 2.0.0.M4. Upgrading fixed it. Thank you.